# Decoding a Function in R

Tags: r, json, function, web-scraping

I found this R Function that can be used to make a Social Network of Reddit Users : https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/RedditExtractoR/versions/2.1.5/topics/user_network

I tried out this function and I was able to plot the network:

```
# install the older version of the library
devtools::install_version("RedditExtractoR", version = "2.1.5", repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org")

library(dplyr)

library(RedditExtractoR)

target_urls <- reddit_urls(search_terms="cats", subreddit="Art", cn_threshold=50)

target_df <- target_urls %>% 
filter(num_comments==min(target_urls$num_comments)) %$% 
URL %>% reddit_content # get the contents of a small thread

network_list <- target_df %>% user_network(include_author=FALSE, agg=TRUE) # extract the network

network_list$plot
```

[image]

**Now, I am trying to figure out how this function ("reddit_content") works in the background.**

The function "reddit_urls" returns a list of comments containing the term "cats" in the subrreddit "Art":

```
> head(target_urls)
      date num_comments                                     title subreddit                                                                                 URL
2 26-08-22          109                     Cat, me, pencil, 2022       Art                     http://www.reddit.com/r/Art/comments/wydak5/cat_me_pencil_2022/
5 24-06-22           51 Cats, me, pen on paper plus digital, 2022       Art http://www.reddit.com/r/Art/comments/vjz27e/cats_me_pen_on_paper_plus_digital_2022/
6 27-07-22          177              Cat operator,me,acrylic,2022       Art              http://www.reddit.com/r/Art/comments/w9983c/cat_operatormeacrylic2022/
7 25-07-22          166          Cat Study, Me, Digital Art, 2022       Art          http://www.reddit.com/r/Art/comments/w81ih8/cat_study_me_digital_art_2022/
8 30-06-22          492             Cat, me, pastel pencils, 2022       Art             http://www.reddit.com/r/Art/comments/voc43v/cat_me_pastel_pencils_2022/
9 08-08-22           83                Cat, me, pen and ink, 2022       Art                http://www.reddit.com/r/Art/comments/wiuhqx/cat_me_pen_and_ink_2022/
```

From here, the **"reddit_content"** function seems to be able to figure out who is writing  the comment and who the comment is being directed to:

```
     test = target_urls[1,5] %>% reddit_content

head(test)

  id structure post_date comm_date num_comments subreddit upvote_prop post_score        author               user comment_score controversiality                                 comment                 title
1  1         1  26-08-22  26-08-22          109       Art        0.98      14101 ninadrawsalot  Something_Average           146                0           He needs some head pats stat! Cat, me, pencil, 2022
2  2       1_1  26-08-22  27-08-22          109       Art        0.98      14101 ninadrawsalot littlebitsofspider            25                0 *Someone snuggle that cat immediately!* Cat, me, pencil, 2022
3  3         2  26-08-22  26-08-22          109       Art        0.98      14101 ninadrawsalot           BrickGun           119                0        "What am I doing with my lives?" Cat, me, pencil, 2022
```

And finally, the "network_list" function is able to transform the above data set into a "graph network" format with edges/nodes (this is what is being visualized):

```
> network_list
$df
# A tibble: 3 x 4
  sender            receiver       count comment                        
  <chr>             <chr>          <dbl> <chr>                          
1 Amazing_SpiderLAN purr_in_ink        1 This so beautiful bud! Congrats
2 BeatlesTypeBeat   macmynameismac     1 Zoom in and you'll see why.    
3 purr_in_ink       elhomerjas         1 Thank you :)
```

**However, I am trying to figure out how the "reddit_content" function works.** I tried using the "getAnywhere" command in R to look at the source code of the "reddit_content" function, but I still can't seem to understand how it works.

As an example:

- 1. Suppose I take the first URL that showed up:       http://www.reddit.com/r/Art/comments/wydak5/cat_me_pencil_2022/
- 2. Then, I take the first comment that shows up on this Reddit post : *Something_Average (26 days ago) He needs some head pats stat!*
- 3. I can now find out the exact link to this comment by using the Reddit Pushshift API :

API Request: https://api.pushshift.io/reddit/comment/search?limit=250&q=*&link_id=wydak5

Reddit Comment Link: https://www.reddit.com/r/Art/comments/wydak5/comment/ilwj4oq/

4. Next, I can use the **"reddit_content"** function to get information about this comment:

Below is an example:

```
 "https://www.reddit.com/r/Art/comments/wydak5/comment/ilwj4oq/" %>% reddit_content # get the contents of a small thread
  |==================================================================================================================================================================================================================| 100%
  id structure post_date comm_date num_comments subreddit upvote_prop post_score        author               user comment_score controversiality                                 comment                 title post_text
1  1         1  26-08-22  26-08-22          109       Art        0.98      14098 ninadrawsalot  Something_Average           143                0           He needs some head pats stat! Cat, me, pencil, 2022          
2  2       1_1  26-08-22  27-08-22          109       Art        0.98      14098 ninadrawsalot littlebitsofspider            25                0 *Someone snuggle that cat immediately!* Cat, me, pencil, 2022          
                                 link    domain                                                                            URL
1 https://i.redd.it/j8rx9llv13k91.jpg i.redd.it https://www.reddit.com/r/Art/comments/wydak5/comment/ilwj4oq/?ref=search_posts
2 https://i.redd.it/j8rx9llv13k91.jpg i.redd.it https://www.reddit.com/r/Art/comments/wydak5/comment/ilwj4oq/?ref=search_posts
```

**But in the end - I still haven't understood the overall process. If I start with this comment here** "https://www.reddit.com/r/Art/comments/wydak5/comment/ilwj4oq/" - **how can I figure out who wrote this comment and who is the comment being directed at?** **If I have a list of many Reddit comments - how can I find out who is writing the comment and to whom the comment is being directed to, and thus create a network visualization?**

Thank you!

Comment: Reading the code of the function `body(RedditExtractoR::reddit_urls)` would be a good way.

Comment: @ jay.sf: thank you! this is a good start! but I am still trying to understand how exactly this function works ... there seem to be many steps and looks confusing ...

Comment: Please see my answer below.

Comment: Thank you! I will start reading it now! BTW I was interested in the "reddit_content" function ... Is this function really able to find out who the reddit comment is directed to?

Comment: I realized that, see _"Similar for RedditExtractoR::reddit_content function"_ section in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if you want `reddit_urls` or `reddit_content` explained, I'll provide both.

If we type `RedditExtractoR::reddit_urls` we get the author's entire source code in the console. To decypher what a function does, we provide all parameters, the function needs.

### Your query

```
target_urls <- reddit_urls(search_terms="cats", subreddit="Art", cn_threshold=50)
```

### Parameters

```
## provide all parameters the function needs, mixture of yours and defaults
search_terms = "cats"; regex_filter = ""; subreddit = "Art"; 
cn_threshold = 50; page_threshold = 1; sort_by = "relevance"; 
wait_time = 2
```

Then we run the function step by step and see what it does.

### Source code, explained

Basically the function runs queries in reddit's JSON database. It has three sections, 1. create query URL, 2. perform query, 3. summarize results to output. Please see for details the comments I've added before each line.

```
function (search_terms = NA, regex_filter = "", subreddit = NA, 
          cn_threshold = 0, page_threshold = 1, sort_by = "relevance", 
          wait_time = 2) 
{
  ## check if input in parameter space
  if (!grepl("^comments$|^new$|^relevance$", sort_by)) {
    stop("sort_by must be either 'new', 'comments' or 'relevance'")
  }
  ## create query URL ---------------------------------------------------------
  ## convert spaces to `+`
  sterms = ifelse(is.na(search_terms), NA, gsub("\\s", "+", 
                                                search_terms))
  ## initialize empty data frame for output
  cached_links = data.frame(date = as.Date(character()), num_comments = numeric(), 
                            title = character(), subreddit = character(), URL = character())
  ## paste carriage return before subreddit (if specified)
  subreddit = ifelse(is.na(subreddit), "", paste0("r/", gsub("\\s+", 
                                                             "+", subreddit), "/"))
  ## paste `q=` before search terms, switch on `restrict_sr`
  sterms = ifelse(is.na(sterms), "", paste0("q=", sterms, "&restrict_sr=on&"))
  ## create prefix
  sterms_prefix = ifelse(sterms == "", "new", "search")
  ## paste everything together to query-URL
  search_address = search_query = paste0("https://www.reddit.com/", 
                                         subreddit, sterms_prefix, ".json?", sterms, "sort=", 
                                         sort_by)
  ## perform query -------------------------------------------------------------
  ## set initial values
  next_page = index = ""
  page_counter = 0
  comm_filter = 10000
  ## perform query loop
  while (is.null(next_page) == FALSE & page_counter < page_threshold & 
         comm_filter >= cn_threshold & length(index) > 0) {
    ## perform query on page #
    search_JSON = tryCatch(RJSONIO::fromJSON(readLines(search_query, 
                                                       warn = FALSE)), error = function(e) NULL)
    ## check if search was unsuccessful
    if (is.null(search_JSON)) {
      cat(paste("Cannot connect to the website, skipping...\n"))
      next
    }
    else {
      ## extract contents
      contents = search_JSON[[2]]$children
      ## extract permalinks
      search_permalink = paste0("http://www.reddit.com", 
                                sapply(seq(contents), function(x) contents[[x]]$data$permalink))
      ## extract number of comments
      search_num_comments = sapply(seq(contents), function(x) contents[[x]]$data$num_comments)
      ## extract title
      search_title = sapply(seq(contents), function(x) contents[[x]]$data$title)
      ## extract score
      search_score = sapply(seq(contents), function(x) contents[[x]]$data$score)
      ## extract subreddit
      search_subreddit = sapply(seq(contents), function(x) contents[[x]]$data$subreddit)
      ## extract index
      index = which(search_num_comments >= cn_threshold & 
                      grepl(regex_filter, search_title, ignore.case = T, 
                            perl = T))
      ## check if index available
      if (length(index) > 0) {
        ## extract search dates
        search_date = format(as.Date(as.POSIXct(unlist(lapply(seq(contents), 
                                                              function(x) contents[[x]]$data$created_utc)), 
                                                origin = "1970-01-01")), "%d-%m-%y")
        ## create temp output
        temp_dat = data.frame(date = search_date, num_comments = search_num_comments, 
                              title = search_title, subreddit = search_subreddit, 
                              URL = search_permalink, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)[index, 
                              ]
        ## rbind `cached_links` from above 
        cached_links = as.data.frame(rbind(cached_links, 
                                           temp_dat))
        ## extract next page's name
        next_page = search_JSON$data$after
        ## extract relevant comment number
        comm_filter = utils::tail(search_num_comments, 
                                  1)
        ## create URL for next query
        search_query = paste0(search_address, "&after=", 
                              next_page)
        ## increase counter by one
        page_counter = page_counter + 1
      }
      ## pause query for a moment
      Sys.sleep(min(2, wait_time))
    }
  }
  ## summarize result ----------------------------------------------------------
  ## filter out dupes
  final_table = cached_links[!duplicated(cached_links), ]
  ## check if results found
  if (dim(final_table)[1] == 0) {
    cat(paste("\nNo results retrieved, check your query"))
  }
  else {
    ## remove rows with no date
    remove_row = which(final_table[, 1] == "")
    if (length(remove_row) > 0) {
      final_table = final_table[-remove_row, ]
    }
    ## return result
    return(final_table)
  }
}
<bytecode: 0x55ffee70a6e0>
  <environment: namespace:RedditExtractoR>
```

Paste parameters and code from above in a script and run it line by line (without function head) and you will be able to understand it well.

### Similar for `RedditExtractoR::reddit_content` function

This function loops over the `URL`s provided and also runs a JSON query, in your case just one.

```
URL=target_df$URL; wait_time=2  ## specify parameters

## run line by line
function (URL, wait_time = 2) 
{
  ## roughly validate URL
  if (is.null(URL) | length(URL) == 0 | !is.character(URL)) {
    stop("invalid URL parameter")
  }
  ## function definitions ------------------------------------------------------
  GetAttribute = function(node, feature) {
    Attribute = node$data[[feature]]
    replies = node$data$replies
    reply.nodes = if (is.list(replies)) 
      replies$data$children
    else NULL
    return(list(Attribute, lapply(reply.nodes, function(x) {
      GetAttribute(x, feature)
    })))
  }
  get.structure = function(node, depth = 0) {
    if (is.null(node)) {
      return(list())
    }
    filter = is.null(node$data$author)
    replies = node$data$replies
    reply.nodes = if (is.list(replies)) 
      replies$data$children
    else NULL
    return(list(paste0(filter, " ", depth), lapply(1:length(reply.nodes), 
                                                   function(x) get.structure(reply.nodes[[x]], paste0(depth, 
                                                                                                      "_", x)))))
  }
  ## initialize empty data frame for output ------------------------------------
  data_extract = data.frame(id = numeric(), structure = character(), 
                            post_date = as.Date(character()), comm_date = as.Date(character()), 
                            num_comments = numeric(), subreddit = character(), upvote_prop = numeric(), 
                            post_score = numeric(), author = character(), user = character(), 
                            comment_score = numeric(), controversiality = numeric(), 
                            comment = character(), title = character(), post_text = character(), 
                            link = character(), domain = character(), URL = character())
  ## loop through URLs ---------------------------------------------------------
  ## start progressbar for console
  pb = utils::txtProgressBar(min = 0, max = length(URL), style = 3)
  ## loop
  for (i in seq(URL)) {
    # i <- 1
    ## care for protocol specification in URL (DOESN'T CHANGE http TO https!)
    if (!grepl("^https?://(.*)", URL[i])) 
      URL[i] = paste0("https://www.", gsub("^.*(reddit\\..*$)", 
                                           "\\1", URL[i]))
    ## paste `ref=search_posts` to URL if not specified
    if (!grepl("\\?ref=search_posts$", URL[i])) 
      URL[i] = paste0(gsub("/$", "", URL[i]), "/?ref=search_posts")
    ## paste everything together
    X = paste0(gsub("\\?ref=search_posts$", "", URL[i]), 
               ".json?limit=500")
    ## run query
    raw_data = tryCatch(RJSONIO::fromJSON(readLines(X, warn = FALSE)), 
                        error = function(e) NULL)
    ## repeat query if unsuccessful
    if (is.null(raw_data)) {
      Sys.sleep(min(1, wait_time))
      raw_data = tryCatch(RJSONIO::fromJSON(readLines(X, 
                                                      warn = FALSE)), error = function(e) NULL)
    }
    ## continue if successful
    if (is.null(raw_data) == FALSE) {
      ## extract meta and main nodes
      meta.node = raw_data[[1]]$data$children[[1]]$data
      main.node = raw_data[[2]]$data$children
      ## if not empty, continue
      if (min(length(meta.node), length(main.node)) > 0) {
        ## get structure of main node, using `get.structure` defined above
        structure = unlist(lapply(1:length(main.node), 
                                  function(x) get.structure(main.node[[x]], x)))
        ## get temporary output df from query results/attributes by converting id, 
        ## structure, post_date, comm_date, num_comments, subreddit, upvote_prop, post_score,
        ## author, user, comment_score, controversiality, comment, title, post_text, 
        ## link, domain, URL into desired formats
        TEMP = data.frame(id = NA, structure = gsub("FALSE ", 
                                                    "", structure[!grepl("TRUE", structure)]), 
                          ## using `GetAttribute` from above
                          post_date = format(as.Date(as.POSIXct(meta.node$created_utc, 
                                                                origin = "1970-01-01")), "%d-%m-%y"), comm_date = format(as.Date(as.POSIXct(unlist(lapply(main.node, 
                                                                                                                                                          function(x) {
                                                                                                                                                            GetAttribute(x, "created_utc")
                                                                                                                                                          })), origin = "1970-01-01")), "%d-%m-%y"), 
                          num_comments = meta.node$num_comments, subreddit = ifelse(is.null(meta.node$subreddit), 
                                                                                    "UNKNOWN", meta.node$subreddit), upvote_prop = meta.node$upvote_ratio, 
                          post_score = meta.node$score, author = meta.node$author, 
                          user = unlist(lapply(main.node, function(x) {
                            GetAttribute(x, "author")
                          })), comment_score = unlist(lapply(main.node, 
                                                             function(x) {
                                                               GetAttribute(x, "score")
                                                             })), controversiality = unlist(lapply(main.node, 
                                                                                                   function(x) {
                                                                                                     GetAttribute(x, "controversiality")
                                                                                                   })), comment = unlist(lapply(main.node, function(x) {
                                                                                                     GetAttribute(x, "body")
                                                                                                   })), title = meta.node$title, post_text = meta.node$selftext, 
                          link = meta.node$url, domain = meta.node$domain, 
                          URL = URL[i], stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
        ## fill ID column
        TEMP$id = 1:nrow(TEMP)
        ## if result isn't empty, rbind to `data_extract` from above
        if (dim(TEMP)[1] > 0 & dim(TEMP)[2] > 0) 
          data_extract = rbind(TEMP, data_extract)
        ## else print message to console
        else print(paste("missed", i, ":", URL[i]))
      }
    }
    ## increment progres bar
    utils::setTxtProgressBar(pb, i)
    ## pause query for a moment
    Sys.sleep(min(2, wait_time))
  }
  ## close progress bar
  close(pb)
  ## return result
  return(data_extract)
}
<bytecode: 0x55ffee946100>
  <environment: namespace:RedditExtractoR>

|============================================================| 100%

## Result
head(data_extract)
# id structure post_date   comm_date num_comments subreddit upvote_prop
# 1  1         1  24-06-22  24-06-22           51       Art        0.98
# 2  2       1_1  24-06-22  24-06-22           51       Art        0.98
# 3  3     1_1_1  24-06-22  25-06-22           51       Art        0.98
# 4  4         2  24-06-22  24-06-22           51       Art        0.98
# 5  5         3  24-06-22  25-06-22           51       Art        0.98
# 6  6       3_1  24-06-22  25-06-22           51       Art        0.98
# post_score      author                  user comment_score controversiality
# 1       7008 purr_in_ink          elhomerjas            49                0
# 2       7008 purr_in_ink         purr_in_ink            17                0
# 3       7008 purr_in_ink   Amazing_SpiderLAN             3                0
# 4       7008 purr_in_ink paprika_number_nine            26                0
# 5       7008 purr_in_ink      macmynameismac            20                0
# 6       7008 purr_in_ink     BeatlesTypeBeat             2                0
# comment
# 1                                                                             what an adorable stack of friendly felines in the work
# 2                                                                                                                       Thank you :)
# 3                                                                                                    This so beautiful bud! Congrats
# 4 If you wouldn\031t mind I would love to get this tattooed. I have three black cats and a tiny little dog and this is just perfect.
# 5                                     For some reason the cats kinda remind me of the little soot balls from Spirited Away, I dig it
# 6                                                                                                        Zoom in and you'll see why.
#                                       title post_text
# 1 Cats, me, pen on paper plus digital, 2022          
# 2 Cats, me, pen on paper plus digital, 2022          
# 3 Cats, me, pen on paper plus digital, 2022          
# 4 Cats, me, pen on paper plus digital, 2022          
# 5 Cats, me, pen on paper plus digital, 2022          
# 6 Cats, me, pen on paper plus digital, 2022          
#                                  link    domain
# 1 https://i.redd.it/d5gxvthc1n791.jpg i.redd.it
# 2 https://i.redd.it/d5gxvthc1n791.jpg i.redd.it
# 3 https://i.redd.it/d5gxvthc1n791.jpg i.redd.it
# 4 https://i.redd.it/d5gxvthc1n791.jpg i.redd.it
# 5 https://i.redd.it/d5gxvthc1n791.jpg i.redd.it
# 6 https://i.redd.it/d5gxvthc1n791.jpg i.redd.it
#                                                                                                    URL
# 1 http://www.reddit.com/r/Art/comments/vjz27e/cats_me_pen_on_paper_plus_digital_2022/?ref=search_posts
# 2 http://www.reddit.com/r/Art/comments/vjz27e/cats_me_pen_on_paper_plus_digital_2022/?ref=search_posts
# 3 http://www.reddit.com/r/Art/comments/vjz27e/cats_me_pen_on_paper_plus_digital_2022/?ref=search_posts
# 4 http://www.reddit.com/r/Art/comments/vjz27e/cats_me_pen_on_paper_plus_digital_2022/?ref=search_posts
# 5 http://www.reddit.com/r/Art/comments/vjz27e/cats_me_pen_on_paper_plus_digital_2022/?ref=search_posts
# 6 http://www.reddit.com/r/Art/comments/vjz27e/cats_me_pen_on_paper_plus_digital_2022/?ref=search_posts
```

**General:** Sometimes, in functions un-exported helper functions are used which might yield an error `Error: object '<object>' not found`. In this case we may add the package with three colons `<pkg>:::<object>`, i.e. `stats:::anova.glmlist` (this can get quite nested!). If there are dots `, ...` we can temporary delete them (or figure something out how to provide the function with the information needed).

### Result

```
final_table
#        date num_comments                                     title
# 1  23-09-22          188           Cat, Me, Pastels on Paper, 2022
# 3  26-08-22          109                     Cat, me, pencil, 2022
# 6  24-06-22           51 Cats, me, pen on paper plus digital, 2022
# 7  27-07-22          177              Cat operator,me,acrylic,2022
# 8  25-07-22          166          Cat Study, Me, Digital Art, 2022
# 9  30-06-22          492             Cat, me, pastel pencils, 2022
# 10 08-08-22           83                Cat, me, pen and ink, 2022
# 24 03-07-22           91   The cat and the lady, me, digital, 2022
#    subreddit
# 1        Art
# 3        Art
# 6        Art
# 7        Art
# 8        Art
# 9        Art
# 10       Art
# 24       Art
#                                                                                    URL
# 1            http://www.reddit.com/r/Art/comments/xlqf2t/cat_me_pastels_on_paper_2022/
# 3                      http://www.reddit.com/r/Art/comments/wydak5/cat_me_pencil_2022/
# 6  http://www.reddit.com/r/Art/comments/vjz27e/cats_me_pen_on_paper_plus_digital_2022/
# 7               http://www.reddit.com/r/Art/comments/w9983c/cat_operatormeacrylic2022/
# 8           http://www.reddit.com/r/Art/comments/w81ih8/cat_study_me_digital_art_2022/
# 9              http://www.reddit.com/r/Art/comments/voc43v/cat_me_pastel_pencils_2022/
# 10                http://www.reddit.com/r/Art/comments/wiuhqx/cat_me_pen_and_ink_2022/
# 24   http://www.reddit.com/r/Art/comments/vq8mv9/the_cat_and_the_lady_me_digital_2022/
```

Comment: In  "GetAttribute = function(node, feature)" .... what is "node" and "feature"? I am trying to find the inputs for the "GetAttribute" function...

Comment: @antonoyaro8 use the search function of your editor, it is used below where `TEMP =` is created.